# Instagram Recent tags API response: -- Are elements in tags array ordered or randomly included in the response array?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to evaluate whether the tags order could improve the relevance of the images being shown to the users. While analyzing the tag API response I noticed that the caption for the image includes the tags as the user intended. But the tags array has a completely different order.

My question is: Does Instagram have an internal algorithm to rank the tags based on relevance/"Any other logic that I would like to know more about" and that's why the tags array has the keys entered in a different order? Or is it just a random parsing process and the order of the tags in the array is meaningless?

Thank you